# numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'parameters'

Tags: python, cvxpy

I have encountered a weird error, reporting  AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'parameters'

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cvxpy as cp

def max_peak(power_signal,overall_ld):

    max_value = overall_ld[0] + power_signal[0]
    for i in range(1,time_slot):
        max_value= cp.maximum(max_value,\
                              overall_ld[i]+power_signal[i])
    return max_value

def offline_opt(overall_load):

    power_signal = cp.Variable(time_slot)
    
    obj_constraints = []

    for time in range(time_slot):
        SoC = 0
        for i in range(time):
            SoC += ((1-agg[3])**(i))*power_signal[time-i] 
        print("agg[0]=",agg[0])
        obj_constraints += [-agg[0]<=SoC, SoC<= agg[0]]
    
    prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(max_peak(power_signal, overall_load)), \
                      constraints=obj_constraints)

    prob.solve(solver=cp.SCS)

    return prob.value

if __name__ == "__main__":

    time_slot = 3

    agg = np.array([10.0,2.0,2.0,0])
    
    offline_opt(np.array([10,5,3]))
```

The problem lies in the line (obj_constraints += [-agg[0]<=SoC, SoC<= agg[0]]). But if I replace agg[0] by 10, -agg[0] by -10. Then it goes through and gives me a result. So I checked the type and value of agg[0],

```
IPdb [2]: agg[0]
10.0

IPdb [4]: type(agg[0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

So what is going on?

Thanks!

Full stack here:

```
  File "", line 1187, in <module>
    off_peak = offline_opt(overall_ld)

  File "", line 261, in offline_opt
    prob.solve(solver=cp.MOSEK)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 462, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 878, in _solve
    for parameter in self.parameters():

  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\utilities\performance_utils.py", line 70, in _compute_once
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)


  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 336, in parameters
    params += constr.parameters()

AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'parameters'
```

UPDATED: The code could be copy and paste run on your machine now. It's self-contained.

Comment: Where is ```agg``` declared? And when did you check that ```agg[0]``` was equal to ```10.0```? If it's not right before the offending line, then it might have been changed after you checked it.

Comment: I believe it is defined in the init main, so in some sense it is a global variable. I use debug mode into the offline opt and variable is correct. If I use print statement in the function, it would print out the same value as well. So I doubt it has to do with cvxpy compiler?@Chaos_Is_Harmony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first iteration of the loops inside `offline_opt`, `time` is set to zero. The inner loop (`for i in range(time)`) doesn't happen (because of `range(0)`), so `SoC` is still zero.

The constraints after the first iterations are:
`[-agg[0]<=0, 0<= agg[0]]`, which are evaluated to boolean (as no expression of variables involved). If you print the value of `obj_constraints` after the first iteration you will see it's `[True, True]`. CVXPY doesn't know what to do with boolean values, as it expected the constraints to include expressions.

A "quick but stupid" fix is to check if `SoC` is of type `cvxpy.Expression` before adding it as a constraint:

```py
if isinstance(SoC, cp.Expression):
    obj_constraints += [-agg[0]<=SoC, SoC<= agg[0]]
```

P.S - instead of `[-agg[0]<=SoC, SoC<= agg[0]]` you can simply write `[SoC <= cp.abs(agg[0])]`

Comment: I think that's the reason. I will give it a try. Though [True, True] should be an expression that be satisfied though. It's nothing like an SAT solver?

Comment: I believe another way to solve (fix) this is changing the index starting from 0 to starting from 1.

Comment: Also, regarding to your [-agg[0]<=SoC, SoC<= agg[0]] you can simply write [SoC <= cp.abs(agg[0])], I tried, the optimization result is a bit different though. 74.4 instead of 75.15 for my experiment. So I'd maybe stick to my method, rather than figuring out a bit of difference of value

Comment: The thing is that cvxpy doesn't know what to do with [True, True]. Its searches for expressions, not for boolean values. That's why he searched for parameters attributes, which do not exist in `numpy.bool`. Regarding the constraint: it's weird it gives a different result, as it is mathematically the same. It might indicate something about the stability of your optimization problem.